# XAMPP doesn't bind to port after installation

Tags: windows-7, xampp

I have successfully installed the latest version of XAMPP on Windows 7 but when I try to run XAMPP it displays an error message and instantly closes and nothing happens!
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What do I need to do to run XAMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable the http.sys service manually via the registry:

1. Launch RegEdit
2. Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP
3. Add a new DWORD (32-bit) value
4. Name it ‘NoRun’ not including the quotes
5. Double click the new property
6. In the Value data field type ’1′ not including quotes and click OK
7. Re-boot your computer

You should now find that Apache will start on port 80!

Its fine! now just open localhost or 127.0.0.1 in a browser. and tell if you dont see the welcome page

Comment: wow .. it seems great .. gonna try .. any problem I'll knock you :)

Comment: i have the same problem in the past. Hope to help :)

Comment: recently i have installed 32 bit win 7 ... right now its not working .. any idea?